# Overriding win/kerberos computer secure channel

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, winrm

Is there a way to completely ignore/override/overrule establishing a secure channel? I'm trying to revert a VM snapshot to test something, and the domain controller is being obnoxious and not allowing the computer access.

I've tried a dozen ways and am pulling my hair out. Just want to say to the server: **Trust this computer. I know what I am doing, I don't care. DO IT.** This should be simple.

Everything I try runs into unknown error, security error, access denied, user/password incorrect, and so on. I'm local admin on the workstation, domain admin on the server, it doesn't matter. Permission denied, access denied, error, syntax error. Any solution on the internet is wrong or out of date. Microsoft has managed to create a situation where, apparently, reverting a domain member VM causes it to become inaccessible.

My requirements for a solution are as follows:

- **No reboots**. If the machine reboots, what I'm trying to do gets ruined. So, it can't reboot. Period. So joining/rejoining the domain is right out.
- Re-establish the secure channel.
- No solutions that require me to go back in time. The machine password has already changed. Policies and registry settings that prevent the password from changing in the future are of no use.

All of these do not work.

- [How to Reset Active Directory Secure Channel If Broken](https://serverfault.com/questions/430042/how-to-reset-active-directory-secure-channel-if-broken) no longer works for server 2019 or 2022.
- Anything using WinRM. Fails with `0x80090322` on this host.
- `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword` Access denied. As domain admin and as local user.
- `Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair -Credential mydomain\Administrator` Access denied.
- `netdom reset /d:mydomain /s:serverhostname /uo:mydomain\Administrator /po:password myvm` or `netdom reset /d:mydomain /s:serverhostname /uo:mydomain\Administrator /po:password myvm`
  Target account name incorrect. Documentation on the syntax of `netdom` is bad, spotty, out of date, and most online examples tend to not work with syntax errors (or not do what I want).
- `nltest /sc_reset:mydomain\serverhostname` error 5, access denied.

Comment: For anyone else - Obviously resetting the computer account is the way to go here.  Additionally, performing this activity *will* disable the system in Active Directory until the computer account is reset, so this is not something that should be done in normal practice, and should only be done as part of a procedure that resets the computer account first.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only incantation that, at least for me, appears to work:

```
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server mydc.mydomain.com -Credential mydomain.com\Administrator
```

Under the following details:

- Assume it's case-sensitive,
- Specify the domain twice (or windows will helpfully infer the local machine name as the missing domain).
- Don't specify the password on the command line.
- Don't try to use a saved credential.
- Run the powershell as an administrator, even if logged in as an administrator.
- Don't run it from the server, only from the local machine.
- Disable windows firewall.